# Native JNI on iOS

Tags: java, c++, ios, java-native-interface

I have been able to successfully build a C++ shared library and use Java native functions to access that code on Android. I am trying to reproduce this effort on iOS. Using CMake, I was able to configure and build my shared library as a .dylib, and load it with `System.loadLibrary()` on my iPhone/iPad emulator. However, when I call a native function I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. A quick check with `nm` verifies that I have exported the JNI functions as I expected. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to modify the native function names for Apple somehow?

Example output from `nm`:

```
000000000011Ce0 T _Java_com_test_Native_getPointer
```

And in `Native.java`:

```
public static native long getPointer();
```

In C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_test_Native_getPointer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    return (jlong)0;
}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/test/Native.getPointer(I)J
```

**SOLVED!**

I had typed the method signature by hand looking at another screen, and accidentally left out a crucial element:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_test_Native_getPointer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, int test)
```

Removing the `int test` resolved the issue.

Comment: Is your `Native` class in the `com.test` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
I had typed the method signature by hand looking at another screen, and accidentally left out a crucial element:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_test_Native_getPointer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, int test)
```

Removing the `int test` resolved the issue.

Comment: Can jni be used with iOS? Because JavaVM framework is only for OS X.